# WP-PageNavi on Custom page template not working

Tags: pagination

this question was asked for many times, but i still unable to fix it. Here is my code

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php   $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $custom_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_key' => 'views_daily',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 15,
        'paged' => $paged
    );

  $custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_args ); ?>

  <?php if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="col3">
                <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                    <div class="entry">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"></a>
                        <div id="morepage-list"><?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<p><strong>Pages:</strong> ', 'after' => '</p>', 'next_or_number' => 'number')); ?></div>
<div class="postdata"></div></div></div></div>
            <?php
                $counter++;
                if ($counter % 3 == 0) echo '<div class="cboth"></div>' ;
            ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
  <?php else:  ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
  <?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I tried some suggestions that i found on web, but nothing helped. It is only showing first 15 results no more. But i want full possible pagination depending on my query details. Sorry for bad language.

Comment: please post the exact code you are using for the `wp_pagenavi()` - using the plugin for custom queries is explained in http://scribu.net/wordpress/wp-pagenavi/wpn-2-74.html

Comment: I tried it, but it did not go on.

Comment: please edit your question to post the full code of your template including the wp_pagenavi code.

Comment: edited and added full code

Comment: have you tried exactly as @Abdul Awal has written in his answer?

Comment: Yes, this code by @Abdul Awal working perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change `<?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>` to the following:

```
<?php wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $custom_query )); ?>
```